# Не работает перемотка RTMP потоков в VLC

Tags: android, vlc, rtmp

Не работает должным образом установка позиции (перемотка) при воспроизведении RTMP потоков (статических файлов, не live) в плеере VLC.

Проблема обнаружилась при разработке приложения на Android для работы с архивом видео по RTMP. В приложении используется плеер LibVLC (de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:1.9.0). Для установки позиции используется следующий код:

```
if (length == 0f)
    mMediaPlayer.setTime(position);
else
    mMediaPlayer.setPosition(position / length);
```

Если указать позицию правее текущей, то плеер "ждет" пока дойдет до этой позиции, остановившись на последнем кадре и потом может начать/не начать воспроизведение с нужной позиции, а если указать слева от текущей, то он сбросится на текущую и продолжит воспроизводить с неё.

Если указать поток другого формата (например, http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4), то установка позиции работает должным образом. На PC в обычном плеере VLC проблема тоже наблюдается, в других плеерах перемотка RTMP потоков работает замечательно.

Можно ли как-то решить этот баг или обойти его и начать нормально устанавливать позицию в LibVLC?

Comment: Сразу замечу, что на форуме VLC не работает форма регистрации, поэтому запостить проблему туда возможности нет.